# One word for a strategy good for each of the cases and a strategy good for only few of the cases

Tags: single-word-requests

I have two strategies that I am applying to my study cases. The first strategy is good for each of the study cases. The second strategy is very good for only few of the study cases but not so good for the rest.

I want to describe these two strategies by a one-word adjective or in a more elegant way than what I just said.

Comment: "general" vs "specific" ?

Comment: I would probably use "all-purpose" and "special-case."

Comment: Definitely "general" vs "specific".

Comment: another option - *narrow* and *broad*. Thin Ship Theory is computationally light, but only works for well for a narrow set of cases. Navier-Stokes solvers are computationally heavy, but can handle a broader range of cases.

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not detail the effort you have already made to find an answer, solutions you have already rejected, and why. Such questions may be closed as lacking research effort until they are edited to include research. Research can take many forms: checking references such as an online English dictionary, thesaurus, or grammar, searching this site for similar questions, searching the web, or putting substantial thought into the question on your own. See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single-word, I suggest...

**"a fully efficient strategy"** should function in the best possible manner with the least waste of time and effort.

**"an imperfect or faulty strategy"** would fail to cover all your study cases.

> - efficient (adj) -  "productive of desired effects" [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/efficient)
> - faulty (adj) - "imperfect or defective" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/faulty)

Answer (score 0):

The two words you need are [strategy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strategy) and [tactic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tactic).  The word strategy by itself implies a wide-ranging plan, covering a multitude of scenarios, while tactic is a more narrow-focused, short-term plan to achieve a specific goal.  The difference is subtle and many people use the terms interchangably (as you have done).  As an example, if the mission to prevent infectious disease, immunization is strategic, cleaning surfaces with bleach is tactical.

This [article](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Strategy_vs_Tactic) does a reasonable job of illustrating the differences.